# How to detect, store and display links using react

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I thought there would be an easy, well documented answer to this but I can't find one anywhere, so maybe I've missed it, sorry if that's the case.

My website has an input field where users can write comments on a post, I want them to be able to put links in these comments. An example input from  a user would be 'I think https://example.com is a great site', I've seen on some sites they have a link button which I guess they use to make this process way simpler. Is there a way to automatically detect the link? Then how is this stored in a database so it can be displayed on a page?

Comment: Have you tried with regex?

Comment: No, but I've heard this is a bad way to do it